# WP NAV MENU - Dropdown always showing

Tags: menus

I'm having some trouble getting the wp_nav_menu to work properly. This is the first time I have worked with this and for the most part it has all come together. My only issue that I am having is with the functionality of the dropdown menus. All of the pages are appearing correctly in the appropriate spot (the primary navigation), but the "fly outs" or drop down submenus are always appearing.

I have of course registered the menu and have placed the wp_nav_menu portion in the navigation. My guess is I have no added support for the dropdown menus to BE drop down menus?

I might also mention that this is a custom theme. I've built it from the bottom up. It's also in a development environment which will be hard to show you guys a live example. For this reason I have attached a screenshot.

```
wp_nav_menu( array(
     'menu' => 'Primary Navigation',
     'container_class' => 'primaryNav',
     'depth'           => 2,
     'fallback_cb' => 'none',
     'theme_location' => 'Primary Navigation',
));

register_nav_menu( 'Primary Navigation', 'Primary Navigation' );

add_theme_support( 'menus' );
```

I've come across two possibilities. I've seen mention of "walker," to which I have little to no understanding of. OR maybe it's as simple as adding some jquery to make them work? I am just under the impression that the functionality should already be there?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Will

Comment: this is a function of your theme's css and isn't specific to WordPress. see the style.css file from the default twentytwelve theme, or search the web for css dropdown menu.

Answer (score 0):

You have to modify style.css. What you should do is look at your source code and see the structure you generated for your menu, and then change your menu accordingly. There are lots of tutorials on the web, all you have to do is Google "css menu tutorial" or "css menu example" and you will find a solution to your problem.